# How can I force magento to not to use SSL on hompage?

Tags: magento

How can I force magento to not to use SSL on hompage?

because I've created a featured product module and now magento is not displaying it and saying insecure content.

It works fine on UAT as there is no ssl certificate.

Comment: Why don't you fix the real issue rather than getting around it and disabling SSL? You just need to make sure all resources (js/images/css etc) you include are included via https and not HTTP

Answer (score 2):

If your page is not suppose to be using SSL, or has unsecure elements, it is better to not use SSL on that page entirely.

A better fix is to remove the below tags from the module `config.xml`:

Your page will be forced to use SSL if admin is found in your `config.xml`. You can find it right below the the first end frontend tag, just uncomment the entire block and you should be fine.

```
<admin>

<routers>
<mymodule>
<use>admin</use>
<args>
<module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
<frontName>mymodule</frontName>
</args>
</mymodule>
</routers>

</admin>
```

Comment: where is this config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect from the secure (https) to the insecure (http) but the rewrite rule http%1 is directing to the secure. just add at your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also you check for admin secure URL in  `system -> Configuration -> web` to set secure in front end no. if you don't have any SSL certificate on your host.

Edit

You can use the _forced_secure option for this:

```
Mage::getUrl('page_url_key', array('_forced_secure' => false));
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters for all options that you can use with getUrl.

Or you have to use

You have to

```
use _type => 'direct_link'

 Mage::getUrl('page_url_key', array( '_nosid' => true, '_store' => 'default', '_type' => 'direct_link' ));
```

Comment: I tried but some browsers are showing the page with https and some with http so if I put '_forced_secure'and then if the browser page is rendered using http then it doesn't display either.

Comment: might be some times will be browser cache issue, first clear all then try